# MagicTexture - how to customize colors?

Tags: shaders

Instead of having all the psychedelic colors of the magic texture feature, I'd like to have 2 or 3 of my own custom colors but in the same swirly pattern. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Fac output of the magic texture, which will give you  black and white image that contains the basic pattern created by the Texture node.

[image]

You can then feed that information to a color ramp and create your own swirly pallete.

[image]

[image]